Gaussian Elimination and How It Affects the Designation of Pivot Columns and Free/Basic Variables
I am learning linear algebra, and I am currently learning about Gaussian Elimination. I understand the method but have deeper, harder-to-articulate questions about Gaussian Elimination. Through my experimentation, I have realized that selecting free and basic variables for a given system is not innate. That is, the free and basic variables Gaussian Elimination "spits" out for a given matrix is not a reflection of the attributes of the variables themselves but of the algorithm's determination.
In other words, suppose we applied elimination to a matrix and obtained our basic and free variables. If we were to rearrange the original matrix by changing the order of the variables (which is reflected in a permutation of the columns that represent variable coefficients), it is likely that our free and basic variables will no longer be the same. Yet, for all intents and purposes, the system and its variables did not change.
Based on these observations, I have two main questions:

Does Gaussian Elimination guarantee that our first non-zero column is a pivot column, meaning that the variable represented by this column is always basic?
How exactly does Gaussian Elimination "choose" free and basic variables? That is, does it favor particular columns to become free or basic?

